# Handling multiple file downloads from Amazon S3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a private bucket that stores full sized images for clients, all thumbnails and smaller sizes are on the webserver.  When the user has multiple images they would like to download, I'd like to zip the aforementioned images, then deliver them as one file to the user.

Currently, the only way I can think of this happening is by transferring files to the web server from S3, zipping, then down to the end user.

It seems there could or should be a better approach to this.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix? Bandwidth usage? Processing time?

Comment: Just trying to reduce the double transfer from S3->Web Server->Client, and go straight from S3->Client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have an EC2 instance to do this. Traffic between EC2 and S3 is free (and as internal traffic, much faster), so you wouldn't be paying for double the bandwidth as you would with an external server.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are Actionscript libraries that allow this to happen client-side eg Fzip...Did you already find a solution?

Comment: I'm currently just transferring files to the web server and then zipping and transferring to the client.  Not optimal, but it works for the time being.
EC2 seems like it would work well, but I haven't looked into it much.